# WordPress URL Routing Querystring isn't passed through

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have a WordPress theme, Woocommerce and Custom Post Types.

A product-url looks like `http://www.[domain].com/product/intel/?model_id=1234`.
Instead of this, we want `http://www.[domain].com/intel-core-i7-9700`.

So I tried:

```
function my_rewrite_rules()
{ 
  global $wp_rewrite;     
  add_rewrite_rule('^intel-core-i7-9700/?$','product/intel/?model_id=1234','top');

}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rules');

function my_query_vars($vars)
{   
  $vars[] = 'model_id';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
```

If I call the url `http://www.[domain].com/intel-core-i7-9700` I get the Intel-Product-Page without Intel-Details because the query-parameter `model_id` isn't passed through.

I tried:

```
$model_id = (isset($wp_query->query_vars['model_id'])) ? $wp_query->query_vars['model_id'] : false;
$model_id = (isset(get_query_var('model_id'))) ? get_query_var('model_id') : false;
```

I flushed rewrite rules, but 'model_id' doesn't exist. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a thought, but you most likely need to whitelist  `model_id` using [add_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, the solution is very simple

```
function my_query_vars($vars)
{   
  $vars[] .= 'model_id';
  $vars[] .= 'product';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
```